# How to proxy an interface in spring

Tags: java, spring, proxy

I want to write an restful service using spring mvc, these service is just an proxy to another webservice. I want to write an interface like and handler like

```
@Controller
public interface UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @WebserviceMethodConfig(moduleName="user", methodName="login")
    public void login(HttpServletRequest request);

}


public class Handler {

    void handle(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args){
        //get the method annotation and invoke the webservice
        // @WebserviceMethodConfig contains the method to route to
    }

}
```

Can some one show me the spring configuration.

Comment: Have a look at Spring Cloud Feign which basically does all that out-of-the-box.

Comment: thanks a lot, I look at that topic and It seems to a better solution.